# Difficulty accessing class method during keystroke event

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, scope

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to code up a simple game involving moving blocks. The blocks are represented by a class `MBlocks` that inherits the `createjs.Container` class, and I have a method I added to it called `select` that should turn the color of a circle in the block to red if it's passed `true` and gray if it's passed `false`. This works fine in the `init()` function, but when I try to call the function from a keystroke event, the console tells me that the `select` method doesn't exist. The lines that aren't working are in the `reactKey` function and look like this: `mBlocks[activeID].select(true);`. I've posted the code below. I can't tell if this is a problem with variable scope or with classes with inheritance or something else entirely. Any advice would be welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>M-Blocks Game</title>
<link href="../_shared/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var stage, mBlocks, bkgd;
    var sw, sh;
    var activeID;

    //MBlock class inherits from Container. MBlocks are squares that in addition to Container
    //properties have velocity and rotational velocity and can be either active or inactive
    //and selected or not selected
    var MBlock = function (x,y,color) {
        this.initialize(x,y,color);
    };
    MBlock.prototype = new createjs.Container();
    MBlock.prototype.Container_initialize = MBlock.prototype.initialize;
    MBlock.prototype.initialize = function(x,y,color) {
        this.Container_initialize();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.selected = false;
        this.color = color;
        this.lightCol = "#DDD";

        //Create and draw block
        this.block = new createjs.Shape();
        this.block.graphics.beginFill(this.color).drawRoundRect(x,y,30,30,7);
        this.addChild(this.block);

        //Create and draw light bulb
        this.light = new createjs.Shape();
        this.light.graphics.beginFill("#DDD").drawCircle(this.x+15,this.y+15,5);
        this.addChild(this.light);
    };
    MBlock.prototype.select = function(sel) {
        this.select = sel;
        this.light.graphics.clear();
        this.lightCol = "red";
        if (sel) this.lightCol = "red";
        else this.lightCol = "#DDD";
        this.light.graphics.beginFill(this.lightCol).drawCircle(this.x+15,this.y+15,5);
    };

    function init() {
        stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

        sw = stage.canvas.width;
        sh = stage.canvas.height;

        activeID = 0;

        bkgd = new createjs.Shape();
        bkgd.graphics.beginFill("#DDF").drawRoundRect(0,0,sw,sh,7);
        stage.addChild(bkgd);

        mBlocks = [];
        mBlocks.push(new MBlock(0,0,"#0F0"));
        mBlocks.push(new MBlock(35,0,"#0F0"));
        activeID = 1;
        mBlocks[1].select(true);
        stage.addChild(mBlocks[0],mBlocks[1]);

        stage.update();
    }

    function reactKey(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==32) { //space key--switch between selection of active mBlocks
            mBlocks[activeID].select(false);
            activeID += 1;
            if (activeID >= mBlocks.length) activeID = 0;
            mBlocks[activeID].select(true);
            stage.update();
        }
    }

    function reactKeyUp(event) {
        //Code here
    }

    function onTick(){
        //Code here
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Wooow! thats a lot of information. Word of advice, could you please reduce the content and be precise with your question before SO makes you feel suicidal with downvotes.

Comment: @shanks Thanks, good to know. I'll whittle down my code and question to the bare essentials and update my post soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling init ?...

In the code you posted you never call init, so, in that case, you haven't defined your mBlocks   array.

Maybe you could do something like this (if you still want available the init function, otherwise you could use an IIFE)

```
function init() {
    //init code
}
init();
```

Using a IIFE

```
(function(){
    //init code
})();
```

A final advice... stop thinking in "classes"... in javascript there is no such thing... at most you have constructors functions that creates objects with a similar structure (creational patterns)... stop thinking in static classes and start thinking in dynamic defnitions.

**EDIT**
After struggle with this problem for a while in the comments, we finally found the mistake that was a typo in the *select* method.

Original code, with typo:

```
MBlock.prototype.select = function(sel) {
    this.select = sel; //Here was the problem
    //more code
};
```

Corrected code:

```
MBlock.prototype.select = function(sel) {
    this.selected = sel;
    //more code
};
```

Comment: I have init() called in the html script upon loading the body, so I don't think `init` not being called is the problem. Using `console.log()`, I've found that in the reactKey function, when the space key is pressed, the code recognizes the elements of the mBlocks array, but it doesn't recognize the `select` function. I assume it's better practice, though, to use an IIFE around the initialization code rather than calling it from HTML, so I will start using that. I'd mark your comment useful if I had enough reputation points.

Comment: I'm trying to use an IIFE around the `init` code, but when I do, the `stage` object doesn't get created properly. I'm wondering if that's because `stage` links to the html `canvas` element, so it matters where it's called from. I think I might have to call `init()` from html. Correct me if I'm wrong. However, my main question is still how to access the `select` method using a keystroke.

Comment: Regarding the original question i've made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/augustoaltman/gjn787re/3/ ... I don't see any problem with scopes and/or context in your code.

On the other hand, back with the IIFE issue, if you are using a canvas then you must wait to your html to load. I didn't know this, so your original aproach was right. Nevertheless if you still want to use an IIFE then you should set the window.onload event handler inside the IIFE with init code an i think that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for setting up the jsfiddle. I was playing with it, and the method was functioning fine when you had `MBlock.prototype = {};` in line 6. When I changed that line to `MBlock.prototype = createjs.Container();` the method stopped working. I made sure to select the CreateJS extension in the top left drop down menu, and I tried adding the default `Container` initialization to the beginning of the `MBlock` initialization as well. Do you know how we can edit that jsfiddle to make it so `MBlock` inherits `Container` and still has a functioning `select` method?

Comment: I finally got it working. The biggest problem turned out to be a really stupid typo...I put `this.select = sel;` instead of `this.selected = sel;` which I guess essentially turned `select` into a boolean variable in the middle of the `select` method. Your fiddle and advice helped a lot.

Comment: Oooh!!.. i didn't see it neither. It was very weird, but now everything makes sense.